# Getting error on application start in WebServer 8 Beta : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: websphere-8, vs-web-application-project

I'm see the following error. Does anyone know the cause?

```
[8/1/15 13:23:02:926 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
[8/1/15 13:23:02:926 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readUTF8(Unknown Source)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:926 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:926 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:926 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:926 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.EJBModuleLocator.locateAnnotations(EJBModuleLocator.java:244)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:926 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ModuleLocator.classContainsAnnotations(ModuleLocator.java:83)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:926 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.EJBModuleLocator.jarArchiveContainsAnnotations(EJBModuleLocator.java:151)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.EJBModuleLocator.isEJBModule(EJBModuleLocator.java:90)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.EjbJar30NoDDImportStrategyImpl$EjbJar30NoDDDiscriminator.hasContent(EjbJar30NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:186)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.EjbJar30NoDDImportStrategyImpl$EjbJar30NoDDDiscriminator.canImport(EjbJar30NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:97)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.openArchive(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:213)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.openUsingChild(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:250)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.openArchive(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:207)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.openUsingChild(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:250)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.openArchive(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:207)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.RootArchiveTypeDescriminatorImpl.openArchive(RootArchiveTypeDescriminatorImpl.java:86)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.openSpecificArchive(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:433)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.fullOpenArchive(ArchiveTypeDiscriminatorImpl.java:411)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1426)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openNestedArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:687)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:927 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.openNestedArchive(ArchiveImpl.java:1955)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.openNestedArchive(EARFileImpl.java:1262)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl.openNestedArchive(LoadStrategyImpl.java:1051)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl.collectFilesFromLooseArchives(LoadStrategyImpl.java:721)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.LoadStrategyImpl.collectFiles(LoadStrategyImpl.java:667)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ContainerImpl.getFiles(ContainerImpl.java:470)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getFiles(EARFileImpl.java:2498)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getModuleFiles(EARFileImpl.java:1074)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForXmiFiles(AppInstallHelper.java:1219)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.checkForEE5Restrictions(AppInstallHelper.java:407)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ValidateEE5RestrictionTask.performTask(ValidateEE5RestrictionTask.java:126)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:312)
[8/1/15 13:23:02:928 IST] 00000018 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks the same as the problem solved by [PM63189](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM63189).